# How I can solve this system of PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For functions

> $\xi = \xi(x,t,u),\;\tau = \tau(x,t,u),\;\eta = \eta(x,t,u),\;g = g(u_{x}),\;h = h(u_{x})$

How I can solve following system of PDEs:

$\xi_{u} = 0,\;\tau_{{u,u}}=0$

$\eta_{{u,u}}-2\,\tau_{{t,u}}=0$

$2\,\tau_{{u}}g \left( u_{{x}} \right) u_{{x}}+2\,\tau_{{x}}g \left( u_
{{x}} \right) -2\,\xi_{{t}}=0
$

$\tau_{{u}} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}u_{{x}}}}g \left( u_{{x}}
 \right)  \right) u_{{x}}-2\,\tau_{{u}}g \left( u_{{x}} \right) +\tau_
{{x}}{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}u_{{x}}}}g \left( u_{{x}} \right) =0
$

$- \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}u_{{x}}}}g \left( u_{{x}} \right) 
 \right) \eta_{{u}}u_{{x}}+ \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}u_{{x}}}}g
 \left( u_{{x}} \right)  \right) \xi_{{x}}u_{{x}}- \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}u_{{x}}}}g \left( u_{{x}} \right)  \right) \eta_{{x}}+2
\,g \left( u_{{x}} \right) \xi_{{x}}-2\,\tau_{{t}}g \left( u_{{x}}
 \right) =0
$

$\tau_{{u,u}}g \left( u_{{x}} \right) {u_{{x}}}^{2}+\tau_{{u}} \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}u_{{x}}}}h \left( u_{{x}} \right)  \right) u_{{x}
}+2\,g \left( u_{{x}} \right) \tau_{{x,u}}u_{{x}}-3\,\tau_{{u}}h
 \left( u_{{x}} \right) +\tau_{{x}}{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}u_{{x}}}}h
 \left( u_{{x}} \right) +g \left( u_{{x}} \right) \tau_{{x,x}}-\tau_{{
t,t}}+2\,\eta_{{t,u}}=0
$

$-\eta_{{u,u}}g \left( u_{{x}} \right) {u_{{x}}}^{2}-2\,g \left( u_{{x}
} \right) \eta_{{x,u}}u_{{x}}+g \left( u_{{x}} \right) \xi_{{x,x}}u_{{
x}}- \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}u_{{x}}}}h \left( u_{{x}} \right) 
 \right) \eta_{{u}}u_{{x}}+ \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}u_{{x}}}}h
 \left( u_{{x}} \right)  \right) \xi_{{x}}u_{{x}}-g \left( u_{{x}}
 \right) \eta_{{x,x}}- \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}u_{{x}}}}h \left( 
u_{{x}} \right)  \right) \eta_{{x}}+\eta_{{u}}h \left( u_{{x}}
 \right) -2\,\tau_{{t}}h \left( u_{{x}} \right) -\xi_{{t,t}}u_{{x}}+
\eta_{{t,t}}=0
$

The expected solution is in the form

> $\xi = \psi(x),\;\tau = \frac{1}{2}a_{2}t^2+a_{1}t+a_{0},\;\eta = \left(\frac{a_{2}t+a_{1}}{2}+c_{5}\right)u+c_{4}xt+\frac{1}{6}c_{3}t^{3}+\frac{1}{2}c_{2}t^{2}+c_{1}t+\beta(x) $

etc. Here $a_{i}$ and $c_{i}$ are constant of integration and $\psi(x), \beta(x)$ are arbitrary functions.

I can solve these equations but I am not sure about how to tackle $u_{x}$ here, which occurs as argument of functions $g(u_{x})$ and $h(u_{x})$.

**Update:** From coefficient of $u_{x}^{2}$, we get $\eta_{u,u} = 0$ and subsequently from second equation we get $\tau_{u,t} = 0.$ Thus we must have

> $ \eta=F_{{4}} \left( x,t \right) u+F_{{5}} \left( x,t \right) 
> ,\tau=F_{{3}} \left( x \right) u+F_{{2}} \left( x,t \right) ,\xi=F_{{6
> }} \left( x,t \right)  
> $

Back substituting $\xi, \tau, \eta$ proves that

> $F_{4}=F_{4}(t)$ and $F_{4,t,t} = 0$ and $F_{3}(t)=F_{3}$

Further, on differentiating first equation wrt $u_{x}$ and subtracting from second equation gives

> $F_{3} = 0$

This further gives

> $F_{2,x} = 0$, $F_{2,t,t}=$constant and $F_{6,x}=0$

Comment: Just curious are these determining equations?

Comment: @MrYouMath: Yeah. These are actually determining equation with unknown functions $g(u_{x})$ and $h(u_{x})$.

Comment: If you use your expressions for $\xi$, $\tau$ and $\eta$ in the equations with $g(u_x)$ and $h(u_x)$ you should be able to get a system of ordinary differential equations in $u_x$. Try to solve it by hand or use maple/mathematica to solve the system.

Comment: @MrYouMath : No no I do not want solve for $u_{x}$. I want to find $\xi, \tau, \eta$ and classification for functions $g(u_{x}), h(u_{x})$.

Comment: hmm ... but you would get expressions for $g(u_x)$ and $h(u_x)$ which are possible.

Comment: Just for you to know - there's a great tool which for a given system of ODEs/PDEs allows one to construct the determining equations and also to solve those. I am talking about the SymmetryAnalysis package for Mathematica which comes together with the book by Brian Cantwell. Which, of course, is not as exhaistive as Olver's one, but also very good.
Book is [here](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=CA73E7970787EE4C6C24F44F75515DBC), package is [here](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=BBA9BA2C370ACE30CA0908822257F363).

Comment: @mavzolej: Can you please write your comment in answer body ? so that I can give you vote.

Comment: @IgotiT, technically it's not an answer.  But you already gave credit to my mania grandiosa ;)

Comment: @mavzolej : I don't have access to Mathematica. We in our institute use Maple as computational tool, neither I have experience of working with it. Can you please solve these equations for me using Mathematica ?

Comment: @IgotiT, 1) What is the original statement of the problem? I guess, you are asked to find the symmetries of a system of equations. But what is the system? Does it consist of only first three equations? 2) What is $u_x$? Is it just a name for a variable? Or is $u$ not an independent variable? (since it can be defferentiated with respect to $x$...)

Comment: @mavzolej: Actually I am trying to verify a paper "Symmetry classification and optimal systems of a non-linear wave equation".

Comment: @IgotiT, ughh these are functional equations with unknown $g$ and $h$... I don't think ayn software may help in this case. Did you manage to finish the calculation? The steps presented here seem to be correct.

Comment: I have solved these determining equations by partial help of Maple. The process is really very tedious, salute to authors of paper.